# Sharding configuration for mysql db

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, nginx, configuration, sharding

I want to test a sharding example using spring boot and mysql database. If I start my mysql database on `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test` and `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test`. Or I could also use the same port but different schemas for testing purpose. Can I use nginx to configure as a reverse proxy to connect to the db depending on the `userid`(which would be my key for sharding? Or what is the best way to test it out. Is it better to shard at the application level itself. I would be using a springboot application for this.

Comment: Please work through more of the details of each approach, then report back to us.  (It's OK to "self-answer" a question, for an extra 15 reputation points.)

Comment: @RickJames - Added the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was overcomplicating things. I needed to use a custom version AbstractRoutingDataSource along with multiple db configuration in spring to get it working. The whole solution can be see [here](https://github.com/newcoder310/experiments/tree/master/shard-example)